# How to pass a list of integer from js to c# controller

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, fetch

I have code send a list of integers to the controller I use `JQuery post` and I want to replace it with `fetch` however my code not working correctly and I have no idea how to solve it my old code:

```
 $.post(url, { ids: id });
```

code using fetch

```
  var ids = new FormData();
  ids.append('ids',id);
  fetch(url, { method: 'POST', body: ids });
```

controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(int[] ids)
{
  return Json(ids)
}
```

First method mapping correctly and the request object as shown in the image below
[image: First method]
Second method request object:
[image: Second method]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fill the `FormData` with an array, you need to do the following

```
var url='url'; //replace With correct url

var ids=[1,2,3,4];
//ids.push(5);

var formData = new FormData();

for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
 formData.append('ids[]', ids[i]);
}

fetch(url, { method: 'POST', body: formData});
```